# parsererror-shown-in-my-code

Tags: solidity

Here is my code:

```
library SafeMath {
  function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a * b;
    assert(a == 0 || c / a == b);
    return c;
  }

  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    assert(b > 0); // Solidity automatically throws when dividing by 0
    uint256 c = a / b;
    assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold
    return c;
  }

  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    assert(b <= a);
    return a - b;
  }

  function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a + b;
    assert(c >= a);
    return c;
  }
}

 interface ERC20 {
    function totalSupply() public view returns(uint supply);

    function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns(uint balance);

    function transfer(address _to, uint _value) public returns(bool success);

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) public returns(bool success);

    function approve(address _spender, uint _value) public returns(bool success);

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns(uint remaining);

    function decimals() public view returns(uint digits);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint _value);
}


    // ERC20 Token Smart Contract
    contract CanergyCoin {

        string public constant name = "CanergyCoin";
        string public constant symbol = "CAN";
        uint8 public constant decimals = 0;
        uint public _totalSupply = 10000000000;
        uint256 public RATE = 1;
        bool public isMinting = false;
        bool public isExchangeListed = false;
        string public constant generatedBy  = "Togen.io by Proof Suite";

        using SafeMath for uint256;
        address public owner;

         // Functions with this modifier can only be executed by the owner
         modifier onlyOwner() {
            if (msg.sender != owner) {
                throw;
            }
             _;
         }

        // Balances for each account
        mapping(address => uint256) balances;
        // Owner of account approves the transfer of an amount to another account
        mapping(address => mapping(address=>uint256)) allowed;

        // Its a payable function works as a token factory.
        function () payable{
            createTokens();
        }

        // Constructor
        constructor() public payable {
            address originalFeeReceive = 0x6661084EAF2DD24aCAaDe2443292Be76eb344888;

            ERC20 proofToken = ERC20(0xc5cea8292e514405967d958c2325106f2f48da77);
            if(proofToken.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= 1000000000000000000){
                msg.sender.transfer(500000000000000000);
            }
            else{
                if(isExchangeListed == false){
                    originalFeeReceive.transfer(500000000000000000);
                }
                else{
                    originalFeeReceive.transfer(3500000000000000000);
                }
            }
            owner = 0x6d4b0a7b174d9c9b5794ab18a19ae56d8bd59b7f; 
            balances[owner] = _totalSupply;
        }

        //allows owner to burn tokens that are not sold in a crowdsale
        function burnTokens(uint256 _value) onlyOwner {

             require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0 );
             _totalSupply = _totalSupply.sub(_value);
             balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);

        }



        // This function creates Tokens  
         function createTokens() payable {
            if(isMinting == true){
                require(msg.value > 0);
                uint256  tokens = msg.value.div(100000000000000).mul(RATE);
                balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(tokens);
                _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(tokens);
                owner.transfer(msg.value);
            }
            else{
                throw;
            }
        }


        function endCrowdsale() onlyOwner {
            isMinting = false;
        }

        function changeCrowdsaleRate(uint256 _value) onlyOwner {
            RATE = _value;
        }



        function totalSupply() constant returns(uint256){
            return _totalSupply;
        }
        // What is the balance of a particular account?
        function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns(uint256){
            return balances[_owner];
        }

         // Transfer the balance from owner's account to another account   
        function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value)  returns(bool) {
            require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0 );
            balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
            balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
            Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
            return true;
        }

    // Send _value amount of tokens from address _from to address _to
    // The transferFrom method is used for a withdraw workflow, allowing contracts to send
    // tokens on your behalf, for example to "deposit" to a contract address and/or to charge
    // fees in sub-currencies; the command should fail unless the _from account has
    // deliberately authorized the sender of the message via some mechanism; we propose
    // these standardized APIs for approval:
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value)  returns(bool) {
        require(allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value && balances[_from] >= _value && _value > 0);
        balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
        allowed[_from][msg.sender] = allowed[_from][msg.sender].sub(_value);
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    // Allow _spender to withdraw from your account, multiple times, up to the _value amount.
    // If this function is called again it overwrites the current allowance with _value.
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns(bool){
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value; 
        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    // Returns the amount which _spender is still allowed to withdraw from _owner
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns(uint256){
        return allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);
```

Comment: Please, don't just dump your code here. Add some details like solidity version, the exact error message you got. What things did you try.

Answer (score 0):

your code is very unclear, the problem is on your constructor

```
constructor() public payable {
        address originalFeeReceive = 0x6661084EAF2DD24aCAaDe2443292Be76eb344888;

        ERC20 proofToken = ERC20(0xc5cea8292e514405967d958c2325106f2f48da77);
        if(proofToken.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= 1000000000000000000){
            msg.sender.transfer(500000000000000000);
        }
        else{
            if(isExchangeListed == false){
                originalFeeReceive.transfer(500000000000000000);
            }
            else{
                originalFeeReceive.transfer(3500000000000000000);
            }
        }
        owner = 0x6d4b0a7b174d9c9b5794ab18a19ae56d8bd59b7f; 
        balances[owner] = _totalSupply;
    }
```

You should put this part into a new method, and add these variables into the constructor and maybe in a struct before for more clarity:

```
  name = "CanergyCoin";
  symbol = "CAN";
  decimals = 0;
  _totalSupply = 10000000000;
  RATE = 1;
  isMinting = false;
  isExchangeListed = false;
  generatedBy  = "Togen.io by Proof Suite";
```

This is the flat version of your contract with the correction implementations, I did the modification and moved all the constructor part into a method call **toRename**, you can copy/paste this on remix it should work

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;



// Flat ERC20
// Updated Jun 7 2019

/**
 * @dev Wrappers over Solidity's arithmetic operations with added overflow
 * checks.
 *
 * Arithmetic operations in Solidity wrap on overflow. This can easily result
 * in bugs, because programmers usually assume that an overflow raises an
 * error, which is the standard behavior in high level programming languages.
 * `SafeMath` restores this intuition by reverting the transaction when an
 * operation overflows.
 *
 * Using this library instead of the unchecked operations eliminates an entire
 * class of bugs, so it's recommended to use it always.
 */
library SafeMath {
    /**
     * @dev Returns the addition of two unsigned integers, reverting on
     * overflow.
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `+` operator.
     *
     * Requirements:
     * - Addition cannot overflow.
     */
    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        require(c >= a, "SafeMath: addition overflow");

        return c;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the subtraction of two unsigned integers, reverting on
     * overflow (when the result is negative).
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `-` operator.
     *
     * Requirements:
     * - Subtraction cannot overflow.
     */
    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b <= a, "SafeMath: subtraction overflow");
        uint256 c = a - b;

        return c;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the multiplication of two unsigned integers, reverting on
     * overflow.
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `*` operator.
     *
     * Requirements:
     * - Multiplication cannot overflow.
     */
    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        // Gas optimization: this is cheaper than requiring 'a' not being zero, but the
        // benefit is lost if 'b' is also tested.
        // See: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/pull/522
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        uint256 c = a * b;
        require(c / a == b, "SafeMath: multiplication overflow");

        return c;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the integer division of two unsigned integers. Reverts on
     * division by zero. The result is rounded towards zero.
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `/` operator. Note: this function uses a
     * `revert` opcode (which leaves remaining gas untouched) while Solidity
     * uses an invalid opcode to revert (consuming all remaining gas).
     *
     * Requirements:
     * - The divisor cannot be zero.
     */
    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        // Solidity only automatically asserts when dividing by 0
        require(b > 0, "SafeMath: division by zero");
        uint256 c = a / b;
        // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold

        return c;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the remainder of dividing two unsigned integers. (unsigned integer modulo),
     * Reverts when dividing by zero.
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `%` operator. This function uses a `revert`
     * opcode (which leaves remaining gas untouched) while Solidity uses an
     * invalid opcode to revert (consuming all remaining gas).
     *
     * Requirements:
     * - The divisor cannot be zero.
     */
    function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b != 0, "SafeMath: modulo by zero");
        return a % b;
    }
}

/**
 * @dev Interface of the ERC20 standard as defined in the EIP. Does not include
 * the optional functions; to access them see `ERC20Detailed`.
 */
interface IERC20 {
    /**
     * @dev Returns the amount of tokens in existence.
     */
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);

    /**
     * @dev Returns the amount of tokens owned by `account`.
     */
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);

    /**
     * @dev Moves `amount` tokens from the caller's account to `recipient`.
     *
     * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
     *
     * Emits a `Transfer` event.
     */
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    /**
     * @dev Returns the remaining number of tokens that `spender` will be
     * allowed to spend on behalf of `owner` through `transferFrom`. This is
     * zero by default.
     *
     * This value changes when `approve` or `transferFrom` are called.
     */
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

    /**
     * @dev Sets `amount` as the allowance of `spender` over the caller's tokens.
     *
     * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
     *
     * > Beware that changing an allowance with this method brings the risk
     * that someone may use both the old and the new allowance by unfortunate
     * transaction ordering. One possible solution to mitigate this race
     * condition is to first reduce the spender's allowance to 0 and set the
     * desired value afterwards:
     * https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20#issuecomment-263524729
     *
     * Emits an `Approval` event.
     */
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    /**
     * @dev Moves `amount` tokens from `sender` to `recipient` using the
     * allowance mechanism. `amount` is then deducted from the caller's
     * allowance.
     *
     * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
     *
     * Emits a `Transfer` event.
     */
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    /**
     * @dev Emitted when `value` tokens are moved from one account (`from`) to
     * another (`to`).
     *
     * Note that `value` may be zero.
     */
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    /**
     * @dev Emitted when the allowance of a `spender` for an `owner` is set by
     * a call to `approve`. `value` is the new allowance.
     */
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

/**
 * @dev Implementation of the `IERC20` interface.
 *
 * This implementation is agnostic to the way tokens are created. This means
 * that a supply mechanism has to be added in a derived contract using `_mint`.
 * For a generic mechanism see `ERC20Mintable`.
 *
 * *For a detailed writeup see our guide [How to implement supply
 * mechanisms](https://forum.zeppelin.solutions/t/how-to-implement-erc20-supply-mechanisms/226).*
 *
 * We have followed general OpenZeppelin guidelines: functions revert instead
 * of returning `false` on failure. This behavior is nonetheless conventional
 * and does not conflict with the expectations of ERC20 applications.
 *
 * Additionally, an `Approval` event is emitted on calls to `transferFrom`.
 * This allows applications to reconstruct the allowance for all accounts just
 * by listening to said events. Other implementations of the EIP may not emit
 * these events, as it isn't required by the specification.
 *
 * Finally, the non-standard `decreaseAllowance` and `increaseAllowance`
 * functions have been added to mitigate the well-known issues around setting
 * allowances. See `IERC20.approve`.
 */
contract ERC20 is IERC20 {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    mapping (address => uint256) private _balances;

    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowances;

    uint256 private _totalSupply;

    /**
     * @dev See `IERC20.totalSupply`.
     */
    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _totalSupply;
    }

    /**
     * @dev See `IERC20.balanceOf`.
     */
    function balanceOf(address account) public view returns (uint256) {
        return _balances[account];
    }

    /**
     * @dev See `IERC20.transfer`.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `recipient` cannot be the zero address.
     * - the caller must have a balance of at least `amount`.
     */
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public returns (bool) {
        _transfer(msg.sender, recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @dev See `IERC20.allowance`.
     */
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view returns (uint256) {
        return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }

    /**
     * @dev See `IERC20.approve`.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `spender` cannot be the zero address.
     */
    function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns (bool) {
        _approve(msg.sender, spender, value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @dev See `IERC20.transferFrom`.
     *
     * Emits an `Approval` event indicating the updated allowance. This is not
     * required by the EIP. See the note at the beginning of `ERC20`;
     *
     * Requirements:
     * - `sender` and `recipient` cannot be the zero address.
     * - `sender` must have a balance of at least `value`.
     * - the caller must have allowance for `sender`'s tokens of at least
     * `amount`.
     */
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public returns (bool) {
        _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        _approve(sender, msg.sender, _allowances[sender][msg.sender].sub(amount));
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Atomically increases the allowance granted to `spender` by the caller.
     *
     * This is an alternative to `approve` that can be used as a mitigation for
     * problems described in `IERC20.approve`.
     *
     * Emits an `Approval` event indicating the updated allowance.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `spender` cannot be the zero address.
     */
    function increaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 addedValue) public returns (bool) {
        _approve(msg.sender, spender, _allowances[msg.sender][spender].add(addedValue));
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Atomically decreases the allowance granted to `spender` by the caller.
     *
     * This is an alternative to `approve` that can be used as a mitigation for
     * problems described in `IERC20.approve`.
     *
     * Emits an `Approval` event indicating the updated allowance.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `spender` cannot be the zero address.
     * - `spender` must have allowance for the caller of at least
     * `subtractedValue`.
     */
    function decreaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 subtractedValue) public returns (bool) {
        _approve(msg.sender, spender, _allowances[msg.sender][spender].sub(subtractedValue));
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Moves tokens `amount` from `sender` to `recipient`.
     *
     * This is internal function is equivalent to `transfer`, and can be used to
     * e.g. implement automatic token fees, slashing mechanisms, etc.
     *
     * Emits a `Transfer` event.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `sender` cannot be the zero address.
     * - `recipient` cannot be the zero address.
     * - `sender` must have a balance of at least `amount`.
     */
    function _transfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) internal {
        require(sender != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(recipient != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");

        _balances[sender] = _balances[sender].sub(amount);
        _balances[recipient] = _balances[recipient].add(amount);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
    }

    /** @dev Creates `amount` tokens and assigns them to `account`, increasing
     * the total supply.
     *
     * Emits a `Transfer` event with `from` set to the zero address.
     *
     * Requirements
     *
     * - `to` cannot be the zero address.
     */
    function _mint(address account, uint256 amount) internal {
        require(account != address(0), "ERC20: mint to the zero address");

        _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(amount);
        _balances[account] = _balances[account].add(amount);
        emit Transfer(address(0), account, amount);
    }

     /**
     * @dev Destoys `amount` tokens from `account`, reducing the
     * total supply.
     *
     * Emits a `Transfer` event with `to` set to the zero address.
     *
     * Requirements
     *
     * - `account` cannot be the zero address.
     * - `account` must have at least `amount` tokens.
     */
    function _burn(address account, uint256 value) internal {
        require(account != address(0), "ERC20: burn from the zero address");

        _totalSupply = _totalSupply.sub(value);
        _balances[account] = _balances[account].sub(value);
        emit Transfer(account, address(0), value);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Sets `amount` as the allowance of `spender` over the `owner`s tokens.
     *
     * This is internal function is equivalent to `approve`, and can be used to
     * e.g. set automatic allowances for certain subsystems, etc.
     *
     * Emits an `Approval` event.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `owner` cannot be the zero address.
     * - `spender` cannot be the zero address.
     */
    function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 value) internal {
        require(owner != address(0), "ERC20: approve from the zero address");
        require(spender != address(0), "ERC20: approve to the zero address");

        _allowances[owner][spender] = value;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, value);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Destoys `amount` tokens from `account`.`amount` is then deducted
     * from the caller's allowance.
     *
     * See `_burn` and `_approve`.
     */
    function _burnFrom(address account, uint256 amount) internal {
        _burn(account, amount);
        _approve(account, msg.sender, _allowances[account][msg.sender].sub(amount));
    }
}

// ERC20 Token Smart Contract
contract CanergyCoin is ERC20 {

    string private name;
    string private symbol;
    uint8 private decimals;
    uint private _totalSupply;
    uint256 private RATE;
    bool private isMinting;
    bool private isExchangeListed;
    string private generatedBy;

    using SafeMath for uint256;
    address public owner;

     // Functions with this modifier can only be executed by the owner
     modifier onlyOwner() {
        if (msg.sender != owner) {
            throw;
        }
         _;
     }

    // Balances for each account
    mapping(address => uint256) balances;
    // Owner of account approves the transfer of an amount to another account
    mapping(address => mapping(address=>uint256)) allowed;

    // Its a payable function works as a token factory.
    function () payable{
        createTokens();
    }


    function toRename() public payable {
                address originalFeeReceive = 0x6661084EAF2DD24aCAaDe2443292Be76eb344888;

        ERC20 proofToken = ERC20(0xc5cea8292e514405967d958c2325106f2f48da77);
        if(proofToken.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= 1000000000000000000){
            msg.sender.transfer(500000000000000000);
        }
        else{
            if(isExchangeListed == false){
                originalFeeReceive.transfer(500000000000000000);
            }
            else{
                originalFeeReceive.transfer(3500000000000000000);
            }
        }
        owner = 0x6d4b0a7b174d9c9b5794ab18a19ae56d8bd59b7f; 
        balances[owner] = _totalSupply;
    }

    // Constructor
    constructor() public payable {

     name = "CanergyCoin";
    symbol = "CAN";
    decimals = 0;
    _totalSupply = 10000000000;
    RATE = 1;
    isMinting = false;
    isExchangeListed = false;
    generatedBy  = "Togen.io by Proof Suite";

        address originalFeeReceive = 0x6661084EAF2DD24aCAaDe2443292Be76eb344888;
    }

    //allows owner to burn tokens that are not sold in a crowdsale
    function burnTokens(uint256 _value) onlyOwner {

         require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0 );
         _totalSupply = _totalSupply.sub(_value);
         balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);

    }



    // This function creates Tokens  
     function createTokens() payable {
        if(isMinting == true){
            require(msg.value > 0);
            uint256  tokens = msg.value.div(100000000000000).mul(RATE);
            balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(tokens);
            _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(tokens);
            owner.transfer(msg.value);
        }
        else{
            throw;
        }
    }


    function endCrowdsale() onlyOwner {
        isMinting = false;
    }

    function changeCrowdsaleRate(uint256 _value) onlyOwner {
        RATE = _value;
    }



    function totalSupply() constant returns(uint256){
        return _totalSupply;
    }
    // What is the balance of a particular account?
    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns(uint256){
        return balances[_owner];
    }

     // Transfer the balance from owner's account to another account   
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value)  returns(bool) {
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0 );
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

// Send _value amount of tokens from address _from to address _to
// The transferFrom method is used for a withdraw workflow, allowing contracts to send
// tokens on your behalf, for example to "deposit" to a contract address and/or to charge
// fees in sub-currencies; the command should fail unless the _from account has
// deliberately authorized the sender of the message via some mechanism; we propose
// these standardized APIs for approval:
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value)  returns(bool) {
    require(allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value && balances[_from] >= _value && _value > 0);
    balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    allowed[_from][msg.sender] = allowed[_from][msg.sender].sub(_value);
    Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
}

// Allow _spender to withdraw from your account, multiple times, up to the _value amount.
// If this function is called again it overwrites the current allowance with _value.
function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns(bool){
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value; 
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
}

// Returns the amount which _spender is still allowed to withdraw from _owner
function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns(uint256){
    return allowed[_owner][_spender];
}

event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);

}
```